# How to programmatically access Public Recorded TV?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

How can I programmatically reference `C:\Users\Public\Public Recorded TV`?

Is there an `Environment.SpecialFolder`?

Comment: whats wrong with: `string PublicRecordedTV = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Public Recorded TV"`?

Comment: Only thinking for the sake of longevity...

Comment: @CCInc the OP rolled back that edit once, why did you make it again?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The question title should make it easier for the others  with the same question to find; the previous title did not.

Comment: @DannyBeckett are you just looking for a special path to the Public Recorded TV folder?  Or just a shorter combination of methods to get the same path?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks. I rolled it back because I don't think there is an `Environment.SpecialFolder` for `Public Recorded TV`, hence the title @CCInc chose was incorrect. I'm looking for a shorter way to get to the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there's a more direct (and localisation-supported) method than this?

```
string PublicRecordedTV = Path.Combine(new DirectoryInfo(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)
).Parent.FullName, "Recorded TV");
```